# Android WebView can't always load the url

Tags: android, android-webview, bolts-framework

Im trying to load a URL using WebView, but the web view does not seem stable - sometimes the page loads 100%, sometimes it stops loading on 30%/50%/75% (random).
I have the WebView being created inside an Android Bolts task, and the WebView is not being showed for the user, it only loads some javascript for future requests.

Code:

```
private Task<Boolean> task_SetupJavascript(){

    final Task<Boolean>.TaskCompletionSource myTask = Task.create();

    WebView webview = new WebView(getActivity());
    final WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript: LocalStorage.set('valueA', 'valueB', 'valueC');");
            myTask.setResult(Boolean.TRUE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            // never fired during tests
            Log.e(TAG,"onReceivedError --->  Something went wrong... "); 
            myTask.setCancelled();
        }
    });

    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            Log.e(TAG, ""+newProgress);
        }
    });

    webview.loadUrl(URL);
    webview.onResume();
    return myTask.getTask();

}
```

I can't figure out what can be causing the WebView to stop loading randomly in the middle of the progress.
Sometimes it fails the first time it runs this task, sometimes it fails after the 3/4/5 time.